# How to show an uploaded image as a canvas background right away?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm using typescript to set as a canvas background an image uploaded by users. However, and I guess due to some binding issue, it only works when the user uploads the file two times. How could I wait for the image to load before trying to set it as a canvas background?

I have tried to run the canvas code only when the `selectedFile` variable is not null (see below) but I'm getting the same error.

```html
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)">
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

```js
private selectedFile: File = null;
private imgURL: any;

onFileChanged(event){
    if(event.target.files.length == 0)  return;
    this.selectedFile = <File> event.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.selectedFile);
    reader.onload = (_event) => {this.imgURL = reader.result;}

    var canvas : any = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctxt = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var background = new Image();
    background.src = this.imgURL;
    background.onload = function () {
      ctxt.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    };
}
```

I expect the canvas to show the selected image as a background. However, the first time the user uploads an image, the output is `GET http://localhost:4200/undefined 404 (Not Found) Image (async)`. When the user uploads a different image, the background is updated to the first selected image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think all you need to do is put your canvas code inside of the `reader.onload` callback.

```
onFileChanged(event) {
  if (event.target.files.length == 0) return;
    this.selectedFile = < File > event.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.selectedFile);

    reader.onload = (_event) => {
      this.imgURL = reader.result;
      var canvas: any = document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctxt = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var background = new Image();
      background.src = this.imgURL;
      background.onload = function() {
      ctxt.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    };
  }
}
```

You were likely getting your error because your `.onload` async callback had not triggered yet and `this.imgURL` would be `undefined` when you tried to use it. Now it waits until we have a value for imgURL before tying to use it.